# Is the 3 bounties per user limit calculated for individual sites or for the network?

Tags: support, bounties

Can a user have 3 active bounties per site and hence more than 3 over the whole SE network?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can have many [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) (more than three) across the entire StackExchange network.

But, on any one given site, the limit is 3.